# Xcode Instruments : Unable to identify the memory leak issue

Tags: swift, realm, xcode-instruments

I'm facing some serious memory-related problems in maintenance project and unable to identify the cause for the issue I'm facing. Please find the attached below image for reference.

Help would be much appreciated.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The Cycles and Roots screenshot you showed doesn't provide any information on what's causing the leak. If you want to find the leaks in your code, switch to the call tree view using the jump bar. Click the Call Tree button at the bottom of the window and select Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes to make it easier to find your code in the call tree view.

[image]

Comment: I tried to what you suggested but the problem is if I check objects call tree then I'm not getting any records in the list but if I cycles and roots then this chart is coming.

Comment: Update your question with what else you tried. Does anything show up in the call tree view if you deselect the Hide System Libraries checkbox? You need to provide more information for anyone to be able to help you. All you provided in your question is that you have a memory issue and a screenshot that nobody can interpret without having access to your code.